# Convertir un array a mayusculas en PHP

Tags: php, array

Hola estimados gusto el saludarlos,

Me podrían echar una mano ya que requiero una función que convierta un arrary en mayúsculas en php mas o menos ya tengo una idea de como hacerlo con una variable pero con el arrary me da error:

```
  <?php

        
        
        // CONVERTIR VARIABLE A MAYUSCULAS
        
        function mayus ($var)
        {
            $proceso = strtoupper($var);
            echo $proceso;
        }
        
        $productos = "playera";
        
        mayus($productos);
        
        // CONVERTIR ARRAY A MAYUSCULAS
```

?>

Comment: Y que error te da?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a convertir todos los elementos del array a mayúsculas?

Comment: Utiliza foreach para recorrerlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es que se pueda convertir un *array* a mayúsculas. Supongo que te refieres a un array de palabras a mayúsculas.

A menos que sea explícitamente una función de impresión, las funciones no deben imprimir el resultado, si no hacer el proceso y dependiendo de ese proceso, retornar (o no) el valor procesado.

O sea tu programa debería quedar así:

```
<?php

function mayus ($var)
{
    $proceso = strtoupper($var);
    return $proceso;
}

$convertido = mayus("playera");
echo $convertido; // PLAYERA
```

PHP tiene una función de alto nivel, [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php), que le aplica una función definida (callback) a cada elemento de un array. Entonces:

```
$datos = array("playera", "arena", "toalla");

$arr_convertido = array_map("mayus", $datos); // "mayus" es la función de arriba
var_dump($arr_convertido); // array("PLAYERA", "ARENA", "TOALLA")
```

O también se puede hacer con un for

```
foreach($datos as $elemento) {
    echo mayus($elemento);
}
// PLAYERAARENATOALLA
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta hermano era justamente lo que buscaba ! Gracias por el apoyo bro

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente señalar que `array_map` admite cualquier función, también aquellas propias de PHP. Significa que le puedes pasar `strtoupper` directamente y convertiría a mayúscula todos los elementos del array.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mArray=array('lorem','ipsum','dolor','siT','aMeT');

$mArray = array_map('strtoupper', $mArray);

foreach ($mArray as $v){
    echo $v.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
LOREM
IPSUM
DOLOR
SIT
AMET
```

Otra forma de imprimirlo, sin el `foreach`:

```
$mArray=array('lorem','ipsum','dolor','siT','aMeT');
$mArray = array_map('strtoupper', $mArray);
echo implode(PHP_EOL,$mArray);
```

**Salida:**

```
LOREM
IPSUM
DOLOR
SIT
AMET
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta hermano era justamente lo que buscaba ! De las dos maneras me sirvio, gracias por el apoyo bro!